# 2 child groups with 1 parent

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I have a problem with making 2 child group to one parent group. I need to o something like

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your table with one parent and one child group first. Right-click on the child group in the Row Groups pane, and select **Add Group -> Adjacent After...**